# change event on select2 always has null value

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Change events fires but inside listener I have alwyas null value.
Initialization

```
       $("#ProductCode").select2({
            dropdownCssClass: "productCodesClass",
            ajax: {
                url: "@string.Format("{0}",Url.Content("~/Order/GetProductsByCatalogue"))",
                data: function(params){
                    var query = {
                        search: params.term,
                        catalogueID: $("#CatalogueID").val(),
                        pageSize: 20
                    }
                    return query;
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    var parseData = $.parseJSON(data);
                    var codes_array = [];
                    $.each(parseData, function (i, p) {
                        codes_array.push({ id: p.ProductID, text: p.ProductCode + '-' + p.Title });
                    });
                    return {
                        results: codes_array
                    };
                }
            }
        });
```

Call change event with a specific value:

```
$("#ProductCodeAlpha").val(pCatalogueID).trigger('change');
```

Inside Event Listener value is always null:

```
 $("#ProductCode").on('change', function (e, source) {
            var productID = $(this).val(); // $(this).val() is ALWAYS NULL 
 });
```

Comment: Log out the data in processResults, probably p.ProductID is null?

Comment: what do you mean by logout? p.ProductID is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [Here](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items)

in section: Preselecting options in an remotely-sourced (AJAX) Select2.

***For Select2 controls that receive their data from an AJAX source, using .val() will not work. The options won't exist yet, because the AJAX request is not fired until the control is opened and/or the user begins searching.... 
The best way to deal with this, therefore, is to simply add the preselected item as a new option.***

Link has also the js code needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this method yet?

```
$("#ProductCode").on("select2:select", function (e, source) { 
   var val = $(e.currentTarget).val();
   console.log(val);
});
```

if no, i hope this helps.

Comment: Select2:select doesn't fire when I call change. I want to programmatically set value to my select. The value exists in options .

Comment: You can destroy your select2 dropdown before setting value to it then recreate select after you done setting your data
   $("#ProductCode").select2("destroy");  // for destroy
   $("#ProductCode").select2(); // recreate
or let jquery do the job. try this out  $("#ProductCode").trigger('change.select2');